# How does Distributed Ledger Technology-based Central Bank Digital Currency provide efficiency gains and serve as a contingency payment medium?

Tags: currency, cryptocurrency, cbdc

From reading [Lannquist,2020, p.7](https://www3.weforum.org/docs/WEF_CBDC_Policymaker_Toolkit.pdf), they said

DLT-based CBDC **"could offer diversification in payment “rails”, providing efficiency gains or serving as a contingency payment medium."**

***I am wondering how DLT-based CBDC can offer the diversification in payment platform, provide efficiency gains and serve as a contingency payment medium?*** Please let me know if this question is not suitable here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think payment rails just refers to the gateway in which a provider (Fintech, Banks, Credit Cards) can offer a payment solution. By this logic, it makes sense that CBDCs depending on how it is being carried out, will increase the diversification in payment platforms.

Taking the example, of China's experiment with CBDCs, users can pay offline to merchants, hence serving as a contingency even if the internet/protocol breaks down.

Regarding efficiency gains, perhaps lowering transaction fees for merchants, thus reducing friction and middleman costs. I think in the UK, Amazon removed Visa as transaction costs are too expensive. I would think the CBDCs have close to none or no transaction fees.

Comment: Hi @Zheng Yuxiang, "**China's experiment with CBDCs, users can pay offline to merchants, hence serving as a contingency even if the internet/protocol breaks down**". it is really interesting to me. How come CBDC can be paid offline?? Is there any paper or document in English about that then?. Much thanks and appreciated

Comment: Hi @Louise , from what I have gathered, the offline payment works via NFC. Here are some links to the papers that describes how the CBDC work in China.

1) https://www.hashkey.com/wp-content/uploads/2020/10/HashKey-Nomura-white-paper.pdf


2) http://www.pbc.gov.cn/en/3688110/3688172/4157443/4293696/2021071614584691871.pdf

Answer (score 0):

I think this paper, although not from an economic prespective, may contain many references about how offline payments work
https://www.mdpi.com/2076-3417/12/9/4488

More  economic CBDC references in general

https://www.researchgate.net/publication/368969492_CBDC_uncertainty_Financial_market_implications

https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S027553192300096X

(sorry if this should be a comment more than an answer, but I don't have enough points to comment yet thought it could be useful to know)